# Is it possible to retrieve the URL from Chrome Customs Tabs after the user has authenticated within a NativeScript-Vue Mobile App?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue, chrome-custom-tabs, discourse

I have created an app that generates user api keys using a discourse site. They are returned as an encrypted payload as a parameter within the return url.

Initially I was using WebView which worked fine but wouldn't allow users to login using Google due to security risks and this is a very important part of the app. I need to be able to read the payload parameter and store that in the app for making API calls.

I have tried multiple NativeScript plugins including `AdvancedWebView`, `AwesomeWebView` and investigated many others that don't seem to reach my requirements.

Is what i'm asking possible in NativeScript-Vue? If not how would I do it?

Comment: How you have implemented Chrome Custom Tabs, are you using any plugin?

Comment: @Manoj I've implemented Chrome Custom Tabs using the aforementioned plugins but these do not allow me to read the payload returned in the query string after authorisation has been completed and the user is redirected.